# undefined ProfilePage index in instagram _scraper_

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api, unirest, undefined-index

for few days am searching for the solution of this issue. This issue was suddenly appeared. It was working fine last week. But not now.

I am getting the error undefined index ProfilePage when I print the userArray in instagram **scraper**. Instead of ProfilePage I am getting LoginAndSignupPage  from the response from mashape/unirest.

Can anyone help for the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram redirect suspicious requests to a login/signup page. They might do this based on the IP you're using. IP ranges from hosters and cloud providers are usually blacklisted or will see the login/signup page.

Comment: Thank you for the information.. Is there any solutions for this...

Comment: You could try to use a proxy.